# Linq -How to get distinct of multiple fields from Anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

userdetails class is defined:

```
class userdetails 
{      
 public string FromUserId;
 public string ToUserID;
 ... more properties
}  
var values = userdetails .Select(i => new { i.FromUserID, 
             i.ToUserID}).Distinct();
```

I want to get list of all the distinct userids from both the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a single list containing unique values from FromUserId and ToUserId fields. In that case you want to union lists of each ID type.

```
var userDetails = new List<userdetails>();
// fill list with values.

var values = userDetails.Select(i => i.FromUserID).Union(userDetails.Select(i => i.ToUserID));
```